RCC setup on fresh laptop fails to build wheel for appium-python-client and generate package metadata
I’m trying to run a special tool called  Robocorp Container (RCC) on a new laptop that doesn’t have anything else installed. RCC is supposed to set up everything it needs without requiring Python or other software on the laptop. I have conda.yaml in which I have mentioned everything like what will be the python, pip version and pip dependencies and all with specific versions.
But when I try to run it with the command:
rcc task run --task "Setup and Run Runner.py"

I get these two problems:

It can't build something called Appium-Python-Client: It’s like trying to build a LEGO car, but some pieces are missing.
It can’t make something called package metadata: Even when I use older versions of things, it still can’t finish setting everything up.

Here’s the part that confuses me: RCC claims it doesn’t need Python or any additional setups, but the error says it’s missing setuptools and wheel —which are tools needed to build everything properly. Why would RCC need these if it's supposed to handle everything on its own?
Error messages:
Here’s the error message for the wheel build problem:
Building wheel for Appium-Python-Client (setup.py): finished with status 'error'
ERROR: Failed building wheel for Appium-Python-Client

And here’s the error for the package metadata issue:
ERROR: Encountered error while generating package metadata

Has anyone experienced this? How can I fix it so RCC grabs everything it needs without requiring Python tools like setuptools and wheel?
I am expecting the when I run the command
rcc task run --task "Setup and Run Runner.py"

so it should make the environment and run my python file.
